# Calculate mean value of a column for each row

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

How do I calculate mean values of Sales and Age columns for Vanilla and Chocolate flavors separately? I

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RENda.png)

Comment: Simply use `groupby`: `df.groupby('Flavor').mean()`.

Comment: Follow the duplicate but use `mean` in place of `sum`